# sts run configuration program arguments too large

Tags: java, configuration, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

STS
Version: 3.4.0.RELEASE
Build Id: 201310051614
java version "1.7.0_65"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_65-b20)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 24.65-b04, mixed mode, sharing)

Runing on
OS Name Microsoft Windows 7 Enterprise
Version 6.1.7601 Service Pack 1 Build 7601
System Type x64-based PC

Having wrongly pasted a large clipboard text item into the Run Configuration/Arguments/Program Arguments I am unable to remove. The UI locks up.
I've tried exiting STS then clicking on the Java Application run configuration in order to delete it but again the UI locks up as soon as the application run configuration is clicked in the list.

Presumably STS is having difficulty with the size. of the arguments.

Is there a way to delete the cached Java Application Run Configuration externally from the STS UI?

Comment: add -clearPersistedState to VM arguments

Comment: Do you mean program command line arguments rather than VM arguments? Either way it made no difference. I've removed workspace/.metadata

Answer (score 0):

The launch confifgurations are stored in eclipse metadata at "${workspace}/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.debug.core/.launches".

You can try to open this location in your OS file browser and deleting the broken configuration that is causing the problem.